# After `git merge`, how do you view diff of "modified" files?

Tags: git, version-control, diff

- I have a feature branch named `feature_xyz` in my git repo that I am working on.
- There was an urgent fix that was needed.
- So I checked out the `master` branch and did some commits to fix the bug.
- I am returning to the feature branch `feature_xyz`.
- After checking out branch `feature_xyz`, I did a `git merge master` to get the commits.
- **After `git merge` I can see `modified` files when I do `git status` but doing `git diff` only shows the conflicts, how do I view the changes for the `modified` files?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

```
git diff --cached
```

---

Longer answer:

- The "modified" files you are seeing after a `git merge` are already "staged".
- The default behavior of `git merge` is to not show staged code changes (aka "modified" files that you are seeing).

To make `git diff` show changes that have been staged you have to use one of the options:

```
#!/bin/bash
git diff --staged
# or
git diff --cached
```

Now you should see the code changes for the "modified" files and the conflicts.

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer.